# Storing workout session/ gym log with Python in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to build an application, where I can enter my reps and weights from my gym session.

My idea was to create a class which contains date, exercise, sets (and for each set reps and weights). This class should be saved to a JSON file.

But I am totally lost and don't know where and how to start. Do you have any ideas and input for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward. This [post](https://changsin.medium.com/how-to-serialize-a-class-object-to-json-in-python-849697a0cd3) explains things beautifully, but I will highlight the main point here. You simply have to use `json.dumps` and pass in the result of the built-in `__dict__` method of the object. Assuming that `session` is the object you created from your class, you could simply do

```
json.dumps(session.__dict__)
```

This isn't the only way. You can refer to the post and select a method of your liking.